# Intuition behind factorization of joint probabilities

Tags: probability, intuition

Given a joint probability distribution $P(A, B, \ldots, Z) $ this can be factorized as

$P(A, B, \ldots, Z) = P(A | B, \ldots, Z) * P(B | C, \dots, Z) * \ldots * P(Y|Z) * P(Z)$

Would it be correct to view this as a tree of events

```
       ----
     /      \
    Z       not(Z)
   /\        /   \
  Y not(Y)   Y  not(Y)
 ...   ...   ...    ...
 /\                  /\
A (not A)    ...    A (not A)
```

and then the probability of all of the events A to Z happening a the same time is: Z happens (=P(Z)), times Y happening given Z has happened (=P(Y|Z)), times X given Y and Z (=P(X|Y,Z)), and so on until A happing given B to Z?

Comment: Yes this is correct.  I personally would have started with $A$ and ended with $Z$: $$P[A \cap B \cap ... \cap Z] = P[A] P[B|A]P[C|A,B]...P[Z|A,...,Y]$$ or used numerical subscripts $A_1, ..., A_n$ to enable this to be used for $n \neq 26$.  Caveat: One potential pitfall of the tree you have drawn is that it might lead one to think that $Y$ can only happen if $Z$ happens (since the only path to $Y$ is through $Z$), which is not true in general.

Comment: Thank you. I have extended the tree to clarify the structure. Perhaps it will be helpful to somebody else. I you post as an answer I would happily mark as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you have done is absolutely correct

Also, this tree diagram is used as an intuitive and helpful tool in probability theory. It also illustrates Bayes' Theorem, helpful to visualize conditional probability, determine patterns of probabilities in infinite-events problems etc.

So yes, you may use the Tree diagram instead of not-so-intuitive algebraic work-ups. It gives the view of complete picture of possibilities and events, so I would personally encourage its use.